# Complexity of an example with only one for loop

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I'm getting started with complexity and I wanted to know why the example given below is O(n^2) and not O(n), would you guys help me? I need it fast for an exam.

```py
l1 = []

for e in range(0, n):
    if e in range(n, 2n):
        l1.append(e**3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the

```
if e in range(n, 2n):
```

is supposed to be

```
for e in range(n, 2n):
```

or even

```
for j in range(n, 2n):
```

If this is the case, then the O(n^2) complexity would make sense since are n iterations happening n times. Meaning the complexity is n * n = n^2.

Otherwise, the loop simply runs n times (range of 0,n) and does not execute

```
if e in range(n, 2n)
```

since e would not fall within this range.